# Angular & Twitter REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I've been hunting for a few hours now and can't seem to find any information specific to my setup so here goes.

I'm using the MEAN stack and wanting to use the Twitter API in my angular app. I have all the required keys and trigger a twitter api authentication on the server side using Node, then pass the token I get in response to my angular pages. I was hoping to be able to use this token to make requests to the api from an angular service. The request I'm trying to get working the moment is to fetch a given user's profile object. I've attached my service method below. The error I get when I run it is a 405 method no allowed, no access-control-allow-origin header is present.

```
angular.module('tms.system').factory('Twitter', ['$log', '$q', '$http', '$window', 'twitter', 'Global', function($log, $q, $http, $window, twitter, Global) {
return {
    findProfile: function(handle) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var config = {
            timeout:3000,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Global.twitterToken,
                'X-Testing' : 'testing'
            }
        };

        $http.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=' + handle, config).
            success(function(data) {
                $log.info(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(status) {
                $log.error(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: The error seems to be that Twitter doesn't allow cross-domain requests. It looks like they support JSONP though, so you can use `$http.jsonp`

Comment: JSONP IS the xdomain solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, as stated in the comments of maurycy's answer {and being myself trying to get tweets just from Angular without succes}, the best approach for this would be to get them from some backend.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use $http.jsonp with a JSON_CALLBACK to get it to work, it's not going to happen with $http.get for sure

Comment: I've tried that previously and get 400 Bad Request error. Upon closer inspection it looks as if the headers I'm setting before I make the request aren't actually being send. I'll take another look at that, is the way I've set them in a config variable the recommended way to do it? I've seen a few using examples using that method.

Comment: I do it personally this way:
it's a function in module definition like 


angular.module('myApp', [//dependency injection if any], function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'xmlhttprequest';
})

Comment: won't this set default all my http request to include any headers I set? I have other http requests I make to other APIs that could have different headers set.

Comment: Turns out you can't modify headers on JSONP requests anyway, looks like I'll have to but some server side solution together instead. Thanks for your help anyway.